# Graphics#drawRect(int, int, int, int) draws bottom corners wrong

Tags: java, graphics

I'm making my own text editing component in java (for practice) and I stumbled upon a problem while implementing text selection.

After a while of debugging rectangle coloring for text selection I decided to just draw a simple rectangle somewhere random in my component, just to see a rectangle and I got this.

[image: Checkout bottom corners]

Notice bottom corners. Left and bottom sides are crossing them by about a pixel.
This rectangle was rendered with Graphics#drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50).

I'm probably missing something obvious. The code in question can be found here https://github.com/linaran/TextEditor/blob/master/src/main/TextEditor.java
in the method paintCursor(Graphics g). Again this rectangle is rendered by one simple command drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50). How come the bottom corners are rendered incorrect?

Comment: You're code has a `drawLine` directly after `drawRect` - where is that line being drawn? In other words, are you just seeing the results of the drawRect + drawLine?

Comment: drawLine is the cursor before the word Hello